# How to use SizeTransition with Text inside a Row without overflows

Tags: flutter

## Problem summary

I'm building simple animation in which, simply, a panel expands to the right on a `onTap` event. The layout can be summarized as follows:

- The panel has many tiles. Each tile has its own:

  - leading icon
  - title text
  - trailing icon
- Each tile, when expanded, shows the three widgets above
- Each tile, when shrinked, just shows the leading icon
- The panel is scrollable to hold *many* icons such as these
- At the end of the panel there's a simple icon which, when tapped, triggers the "expand" or "shrink" animation
- The animation is built with an `AnimatedContainer` on the panel and a `SizeTransition` on the single tiles (via one single controller on the parent class)

The problem is simple: when the tiles shrink, their inner `text` overflows in the row.

## Sample code

I just made this [reproducible example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1d3520827c1393bdb2a5f979dcb39171).

## The obvious solution isn't helping me out

The most obvious solution is to simply wrap the `Text` inside a `Flexible` Widget: this advised by Flutter's docs and it makes sense, but unluckily it *completely breaks* my Layout.

Flexible introduces a `flex` factor that in this context is 100% unwanted.

I want my leading icons to be *always at the end* of the row, so my `Spacer` widget should "prevail" there.

I can't just play with `flex` factors there, as it would unintendedly hide text depending on its value.

## Another code smell

Another thing I really don't like is the fact that I have to build a controller on the parent class, but I'm not actually using it on the parent class (I'm just exploiting it so I can give it to the children).

I'm new to animations in Flutter so I'm kinda confused on how I should orchestrate the whole thing here.

**Any help will be appreciated / upvoted / accepted**. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you in a right way you just need set sizes for `Row` inside of `SizeTransition` instead of `Container` sizes

Here is your modified sample https://dartpad.dev/?id=a2408d29a1e8c6ce7a1cef8f21e7491d

Comment: I can't believe it was something this trivial. Yet I had no clue how to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try an **OverflowBox** or a **FittedBox** (wrapping your text), depending on the result you want to achieve.

Comment: I already tried that, but the problem persists. With `FittedBox` the text shrinks but eventually throw the error anyways, while `OverflowBox` throws weird errors I am unable to understand at the moment.